# Exception while addding plugins to Jenkins using Configuration-As-Code plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have used configuration-as-code plugin to add some plugins to Jenkins. Provided below is my yaml file.

```
jenkins:
  systemMessage: "welcome"
plugins:
  required:
    mesos: latest
```

But it gives following exception

[image]

Any help on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current version of [Jenkins Configuration as Code (a.k.a. `JCasC`)](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin) i.e., `1.29`  does not support plugin installation.

For installation of plugins, you will have to use one of these as per [official link](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin#installing-plugins):

- Dockers users can use:
  https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/#preinstalling-plugins
- Kubernetes users:
  https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins

Also check [ISSUE-962](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/issues/962)